# Why does my panel move when i resize the window?

Tags: java, panel, frame

In this code I have created a Frame with a Panel. When the user clicks in the panel the x and y point of the location that was clicked will be displayed.

The goal is to add the panel in order to generate 0,8 when the top left corner is clicked. However, I cannot generate that point unless i resize the window?

Why is that and how would I accomplish this without having to resize the window?

Before resizing the window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXwgu.png

After resizing the window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qupa3.png

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Proj07Runner {
  Proj07Runner(){//overloaded constructor
  //The purpose of this constructor is to display
  // the certification: modified very slightly from Proj03Runner
    System.out.println(
    "Terminal Text");
    new GUI(); //instantiate a GUI
  }//end main
}//end class Proj07Runner
//=======================================================//


class MyFrame extends Frame{
  int clickX;
  int clickY;

  MyFrame(){
    setTitle("zzz");
    setSize(300,100);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(
             "" + clickX + ", " + clickY, clickX, clickY);
  }//end paint()
}//end class MyFrame
//=======================================================//


//Subclass Panel in order to override the paint method.
class MyPanel extends Panel{
  int clickX;
  int clickY;
 
  MyPanel(){//constructor
    setSize(300,100); // set size of Panel
    setBackground(Color.yellow); // make panel yellow
  }//end constructor
  
  public void paint(Graphics g){//override paint() method
    //display coordinate information on the object
    g.drawString(
            "" + clickX + ", " + clickY, clickX, clickY);
  }//end paint()
}//end class MyFrame
//---------------------------------------------------------


class GUI {
  public GUI(){//constructor
    //Instantiate an object of type MyPanel
    MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();    
    //Instantiate an object of type MyFrame
    MyFrame displayWindow = new MyFrame();
    displayWindow.setVisible(true);
    displayWindow.add(myPanel);

    WProc1 winProcCmd1 = new WProc1();
    displayWindow.addWindowListener(winProcCmd1);  
    //Instantiate and register Listener object which will 
    // process mouse events on MyFrame or myPanel object.
    MouseProc mouseProcCmd = new MouseProc(displayWindow, myPanel);
    displayWindow.addMouseListener(mouseProcCmd);
    myPanel.addMouseListener(mouseProcCmd); 
  }//end constructor
}//end class GUI definition
//=======================================================//


class MouseProc extends MouseAdapter{
  //save references to the objects here
  MyFrame refToFrame;
  MyPanel refToPanel;
  
  MouseProc(MyFrame inFrame,MyPanel inPanel){//constructor
    refToFrame = inFrame;//save references to the frames
    refToPanel = inPanel;
  }//end constructor

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    refToPanel.clickX = e.getX();
    refToPanel.clickY = e.getY();
    refToPanel.repaint();
  }//end mousePressed()
}//end class MouseProc
//---------------------------------------------------------

class WProc1 extends WindowAdapter{
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    System.exit(0);
  }//end windowClosing()
}//end class WProc1
//=======================================================//


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qupa3.png
```

Comment: Skimming though the code, you're breaking the paint chain, which isn't good.  Also you're painting directly onto a frame, which is also, not good.  You need to beware that a frame contains the frame decorations, so it's possible to paint under those.

Comment: I would recommend looking at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to get a better understanding of how painting works in Swing, I'd also recommend against overriding ANY paint method of a top level container, like `Frame`, in fact, I'd actually recommend against using AWT based component directly and prefer Swing based components, or if you're not stuck to a framework, JavaFX

Comment: You have two issues, first both `myPanel` and `displayWindow` have the same action listener, so they will both update the values of `clickX` and `clickY`, but the reason for the difference is inside the `mousePressed` event, where using `e.getY()` will get the location relative to the window (including the title bar), it will not get the location of the actual click "inside" the panel. So if you want to show 0,8 instead of 0,42, then remove `displayWindow.addMouseListener(mouseProcCmd);` and change `refToPanel.clickY = e.getY();` to be `refToPanel.clickY = e.getY() - titleBarHeight;`

Comment: what is another way to do ```refToPanel.clickY = e.getY() - titleBarHeight;``` when this error comes up: titleBarHeight cannot be resolved to a variable